# How to remove "white area" in Microsoft Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I installed Outlook 2019. In the mail view there is a big white area between the mail list on the left and the task list on the right. How can I remove this area?

Same problem applies to calendar and task view.

[image: Outlook 19 white area]

[image: Calender/Task View white area]

Comment: How long has this been an issue? My first thought was that there was some Outlook prompt that isn't loading completely and is just showing up as white space that you can't Alt+Tab to.

Comment: @mael' I installed Outlook yesterday. The issue occures every time when I start Outlook. I restarted Outlook and my computer multiple times but it didn't help.

Comment: are you receiving e-mail correctly? I would try signing out of your Outlook account and signing back in

Comment: Receiving (and sending) mails works fine. I already tried to remove my mail account and then add it again, but the issue remains.

Comment: is the white space always in the same location, regardless of where you move your Outlook window?

Comment: when I move the Outlook window, the white space moves with it. I.e. it is always at the same location relative to the outlook window (it seems to "belong" to Outlook)

Comment: have you tried running any of the repair options from `Control Panel` > `Programs and Features`?

Comment: yes, I tried the quick repair option and the online repair option. I also tried to uninstall Outlook and install it again. The issue remained

Comment: if you grab your `To-Do` bar on the right and drag it over the white space, does it change anything?

Comment: The To-Do bar becomes bigger and the white space smaller. But there is still a white space remaining that partly covers the e-mail list.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution: There is an issue where Outlook stops rendering properly in the 32-bit version of Outlook. See [here](http://workshare.force.com/knowledgebase/articles/Help_Articles/32-bit-Outlook-displays-black-boxes-white-boxes-and-or-blank-content) here for details.

I uninstalled the 32-bit version and then installed the 64-bit version explicitly. Originally I had chosen `Setup.exe` from the disk image which unfortunately installed the 32-bit version. This time I chose `Setup64.exe` from the subfolder `Office`.